# Linq Call - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code which when run an exception of type 'EntityCommandExecutionException' is raised.

The line which Visual Studio points to:

```
else if (item.FirstOrDefault().InspectionEquipmentTypes.Any())
```

The inner details of the exception say that:

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

My question is the line which raised the error is not trying to use a database/datareader (to my knowledge) so I am unsure why this exception is being generated.

Edit:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Entities.Inspection>> GetUnscheduledBatchInspections(Entities.EntityModel context)
    {
        var results = context.Inspections.Where(w =>
            w.InspectionBatchNo != null
            && w.IsCancelled == false
            && !w.CalendarItems.Any()
            && w.Duration.HasValue).GroupBy(g => g.InspectionBatchNo);
        return results;
    }
```

Calling method:

```
    private void MapBatchInspectionsToViewModel(ref SchedulerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var batchInspections = SchedulerManager.GetUnscheduledBatchInspections(this.Context);

        foreach (var item in batchInspections)
        {
            var bigi = new BatchInspectionGridItem();
            if (item.Any())
            {
                bigi.BatchInspectionNo = item.First().InspectionBatchNo;

                if (item.FirstOrDefault().EquipmentTypeID != null)
                {
                    bigi.EquipmentTypeName = item.FirstOrDefault().EquipmentType.Description;
                }
                else if (item.FirstOrDefault().InspectionEquipmentTypes.Any())
                {
                    bigi.EquipmentTypeName = string.Join(" / ", item.FirstOrDefault().InspectionEquipmentTypes.Select(s => s.EquipmentType.Description));
                }
                bigi.CustomerName = item.First().CustomerSite.Customer.CustomerName;
                bigi.CustomerID = item.First().CustomerSite.Customer.CustomerID;
                bigi.NumberOfInspections = item.Count();
                bigi.TotalDuration = item.Sum(s => s.Duration);
            }

            viewModel.BatchInspectionGridViewModel.Add(bigi);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some more code to show the definition of how `item` is created?

Comment: You're using LINQ inside a conditional expression. It's conceivable that previous conditional expressions have the context tied up for similar checks.

Comment: I guess you're using either linq to sql or linq to entity framework. Either way, you can set up the connection to the dbase to allow multiple active result sets that enable you to use multiple DataReaders simultaneously. Just add the following to your connection string: MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens: while you loop through `batchInspections` the database reader is reading this collection from the database. Within the loop you do new database reads by the numerous `First(OrDefault)` calls, the `Sum` and the `Count`. That causes the exception 'There is already an open DataReader...'.

As said by George Lica, you can probably solve this by setting `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string.

Or you can finish reading `batchInspections` before the loop starts itereating by...

```
foreach (var item in batchInspections.ToList())
```

But it is far more efficient to first collect the data you're going to need and *then* loop through them:

```
foreach (var item in batchInspections
            .Select(b => new 
                         {
                             First = b.FirstOrDefault(),
                             Count = b.Count(),
                             Sum = b.Sum(s => s.Duration)
                         } )
            .ToList())
{
    var bigi = new BatchInspectionGridItem();
    if (item.Any())
    {
        bigi.BatchInspectionNo = item.First.InspectionBatchNo;

        if (item.First.EquipmentTypeID != null)
        {
            bigi.EquipmentTypeName = item.First.EquipmentType.Description;
        }
        else if (item.First.InspectionEquipmentTypes.Any())
        {
            bigi.EquipmentTypeName = string.Join(" / ", item.First.InspectionEquipmentTypes.Select(s => s.EquipmentType.Description));
        }
        bigi.CustomerName = item.First.CustomerSite.Customer.CustomerName;
        bigi.CustomerID = item.First.CustomerSite.Customer.CustomerID;
        bigi.NumberOfInspections = item.Count;
        bigi.TotalDuration = item.Sum;
    }

    viewModel.BatchInspectionGridViewModel.Add(bigi);
}
```

I hope that `SchedulerManager.GetUnscheduledBatchInspections` returns an `IQueryable`, so that the subsequent `Select` into the anonymous type will be translated into SQL.

It must be said though that activating MARS is nearly always a good idea with Entity Framework, because lazy loading has a way of causing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you make queries in a nested way.

```
item.FirstOrDefault().InspectionEquipmentTypes.ToList().Any()
```

may work. I am not sure though. Try simplifying the nested queries. For example don't make queries like:

```
items.Where(/*some condition*/).Any();
```

instead make

```
items.Any(/*some condition*/);
```

Comment: Can you explain why items.Where("condition").Any(); is worse than items.Any("condition") ? I presume .Any() just checks the resultset and does not run extra queries?

Comment: Although there sure are technical benefits, I'm not fully acknowleded about them, but increasing the readability would be enough of a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have nested queries ( i don't recommend that, i would rather do separate queries and link entities using some hashing data structures) and you are using sql server, you actually have an alternative: activate MARS. To activate it, just add in your connection string MultipleActiveResultSets=True. For more details follow this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx